# A is involutory matrix so is every natural power of A

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is involutory matrix then every natural power of A is involutory. Its written on Wikipedia 
I didn't get it. Suppose $A^7=A^6.A \ne I$.

So how come A is involutory ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix Fourth property.

Comment: You are thinking of the converse. The property is: If $A^2=I$ then $(A^n)^2=(A^2)^n=I$. The converse it not true. If $A=(e^{2\pi i/4})$, then $A^4=(1)=I$, but $A^2=(e^{\pi i})=(-1)\neq (1)=I$.

Comment: @b00nheT That I read. The first line didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Only even power makes it involuntary matrix right?

Comment: No, the converse is just not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article, there is only one direction specified:

> *If* $\mathbf{A}$ is involutory, then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\mathbf{A}^n$ is involutory, and
>
> - if $n$ is odd, then $\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{A}$
> - if $n$ is even, then $\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{I}$

In other words, *every* power is again involutory, as they relate to either $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ was supposed to and $\mathbf{I}$, the identity, trivially is.

Where your confusion comes from, is that you've read the statement as the converse implication, i.e. that if $\mathbf{A}^n$ is involutory, then $\mathbf{A}$ is which is generally not true.

**EDIT:** I give a proof the above mentioned statement: Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an involution, i.e. $\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{I}$. Let's look a the power $\mathbf{A}^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $n$ be even, i.e. $n=2k$. Now, we can write $\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{A}^2\dots\mathbf{A}^2$($k$ times). But now, $$\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{A}^2\dots\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{I}\dots\mathbf{I}=\mathbf{I}$$ For $n$ odd, i.e. $n=2k+1$, we may write $\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{A}^2\dots\mathbf{A}^2\mathbf{A}$ with k many $\mathbf{A}^2$. Now, $$\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{A}^2\dots\mathbf{A}^2\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}\dots\mathbf{I}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}$$.

As $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{I}$ are involutory and 
either$\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{A}^n=\mathbf{I}$, we have that $\mathbf{A}^n$ with the desired equalities shown before.

Comment: Meaning that if A is involutory and any power raised to it will be involutory as well. Suppose I say A is involutory how will you prove $A^7$ is involuntary. I am not just getting it.

Comment: @Damn1o1 I proved it in my comment above. When $A$ is involutory, this is when $A^2=I$, then $A^7$ is involutory because $(A^7)^2=(A^2)^7=I^7=I$.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft Ohh I got it now! Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your comment, but I've included a proof of the statement in the edit anyway.

Comment: @zzuussee Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $A$ is *involutory* if $A^2=I$. In particular $A$ is invertible.

An elementary property of powers is that $(A^m)^n=A^{mn}=(A^n)^m$. If $A$ is involutory, then
$$
(A^n)^2=(A^2)^n=I^n=I
$$
so $A^n$ is involutory as well.

Actually, if $n=2k+1$ is odd, then $A^n=A^{2k+1}=A^{2k}A=IA=A$; if $n=2k$ is even, then $A^n=A^{2k}=I$.

---

If $A^7=A^6$ *and* $A$ is invertible, then $A=I$.